# reportLab using a lot of memory generating large PDF files

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using reportLab to generate a PDF with many images spread over many pages. It appears that the more images and pages I add, the more memory reportLab is using.

Is there some way to get it to flush per page, or at least not cache the images in memory?

Comment: After x-pages you can call the build method and start a new file/template then merge the resulting PDFs after the fact.

Comment: @bdoubleu Yes, that's my current planned workaround. It has one drawback of not being able to share an image across pages I believe.

Comment: @bdoubleu In practice this does not appear to work. Calling `canvas.save()` and creating a new Canvas results in higher memory usage. There's something in reportLab that isn't cleaning up correctly. :(

Comment: Does [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/reportlab-converting-hundreds) help?